# how to hide the notificatications in android

Tags: android, push-notification

after receiving the notification if we click the notification it should open the notification activity page and should hide the received notification.

```
package com.androidexample.notification;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class NotificationAlert extends Activity {

    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.notification_alert);

        final Button notify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notify);

        notify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    /*********** Create notification ***********/

                    final NotificationManager mgr=
                        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,
                                                                    "Android Example Status message!",
                                                                    System.currentTimeMillis());


                    // This pending intent will open after notification click
                    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, 
                                                     new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotifyMessage.class),
                                                            0);

                    note.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), "Android Example Notification Title",
                                            "This is the android example notification message", i);


                    //After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
                    //note.number=2;
                    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);


            } 
        });

    }
}
```

this is the code ..please help out in resolving..
thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in `onCreate()` of your `NotifyMessage.class` activity

`String ns = this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
  NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(ns);
  nMgr.cancelAll();`

Hope this will solve your issue